# Text expander paste function to format a phone number

Tags: javascript, textexpander

I am trying to create a Text Expander snippet to speed up a workflow.  I want to copy a number in this format: +12345678910 and be able to past this it like this: **(234) 567-8910** and make the font bold.

The closest script I've found is:

```
var s2 = (﻿""﻿+TextExpander.pasteboardText)﻿.﻿replace﻿(﻿/\D/g﻿, ''﻿)﻿;﻿
var m = s2.﻿match﻿(﻿/^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})$/﻿)﻿;﻿
if﻿(m) `(${m[1]}) ${m[2]}-${m[3]}`﻿;﻿
else ""﻿;
```

This allows me to copy the "2345678910" portion of the data and and have it pasted as (234) 567-8910. Any suggestions would be super helpful, I'm interested in learning.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the `+1` to your regex, but don't include it in a group:
`/^\+1(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})$/`

[regexer](https://regexr.com/6jkre) can be super helpful for flushing these issues out~

Comment: regexr is super helpful.  Thanks, that really cleared things up for me.  So, your suggestion works however it think i'm still missing something.  When I Copy "+12345678910" and then use the designated TextExapnder snippet the return is nothing `""`.  So I had the TE return `s2` like this:`var s2 = (""+TextExpander.pasteboardText).replace(/\D/g, '');
//var s2="+15302563702"
var m = s2.match(/^\+1(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})$/);
if(m) `(${m[1]}) ${m[2]}-${m[3]}`;
else s2;`.     and it returned: 12345678910 without a "+" any idea?

Comment: however, removing the `\+` solve my problem.

Comment: Here `.replace(/\D/g, '')` you already remove the `+`, hadn't noticed that before.